# MySQL query that find matches that are ecual

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table called "MyTable"

**ID--- a --- b**
  10---20---42
  11---20---43
  12---20---44
  13---21---44
  14---20---45
  14---22---44
  14---22---43
  14---24---45
  14---22---42

I am trying to write a query that gets me into the following results. 
Examples.

```
SELECT b FROM mytable WHERE a=(20, 21, 22)
```

This returns 44 as it is the only number that is common.

```
SELECT b FROM mytable WHERE a=(20, 22) AND b is the same
```

This returns 42 and also 43 because both match

```
SELECT b FROM mytable WHERE a=(22, 24) AND b is the same
```

This returns nothing because the b value is different between the numbers in column a.

Thanks for your help

(found an answer I guess)

```js
 
select b 
from MyTable 
group by b 
having sum(a = 20) > 0 and // -- has id = 20 
sum(a = 21) > 0 // -- has id = 21
```

Comment: It is similar but not the same. This is not valid Barmar

Comment: select b
from MyTable
group by b
having sum(a = 20) > 0 and -- has id = 2
       sum(a = 21) > 0     -- has id = 4

Comment: Ok Barmar. I think I got the answer from the post you linked. I even edited my original post to include the answer

Answer (score 0):

For queries like that where you want to narrow down by a set you can do it one of two ways, the long way:

```
SELECT b FROM mytable WHERE a=20 OR a=21 OR a=22
```

Or the short way, by using the IN keyword:

```
SELECT b FROM mytable WHERE a IN (20, 21, 22)
```

for your query 'SELECT b FROM mytable WHERE a=(20, 22) AND b is the same' you can still use the same idea, but do:

```
SELECT b FROM mytable WHERE a IN(20, 22) AND b=a
```